# Paperclip change default path and hash image names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip

I'm new to Rails and using Paperclip, I have it set up on my model already without issue. I just don't like the path it's generating for my images right now (`:root_path/system/users/avatars/000/000/001`) I really don't even understand it. How can I modify this default path for my images to something more friendly? And how can I hash the image names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your model, you can set the default path, styles and url as so:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
:styles => { :large => "500x500>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "/images/:id/:style/:filename"
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do the hash deal? That worked for the paths, thank you.

Comment: hash deal? can you clarify a little?

Comment: Do you know of any way I can make the files be saved with a hash name instead of their original name, or more like hash the path to my images to protect my folder structure.

Comment: You can find all hashes available in [this list](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Interpolations#attachment-instance_method)

Answer (score 3):

you can setup the hash on the paperclip initializer file (`config/initializers/paperclip_defaults.rb`)

Quoting from paperclip [wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Hashing):

> `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
>    :path => ":class/:attachment/:hash/:style.:extension",
>    :hash_secret => "SOME_RANDOM_SECRET"
>   })`

The `:hash` part is generated from `:hash_secret` and the pattern given by the `:hash_data` option, which by default is `":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at"`.